# ClassNotFoundException : org.apache.http.util.Args - how to upload file using MultipartEntityBuilder?

Tags: dependencies, httpclient

This is what I am getting

> org.apache.http.util.Args. Stacktrace follows: Message:
>   org.apache.http.util.Args
>       Line | Method
>   ->>  366 | run                                in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
>   - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - |    355 | run                                in     '' |    354 | findClass . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.net.URLClassLoader |    423
>   | loadClass                          in java.lang.ClassLoader |     48
>   |  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in
>   org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.AbstractContentBod |    155 |
>                                in
>   org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody |    121 | addTextBody
>   . . . . . . . . . . .  in
>   org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder |    271 |
>   $tt__getResponseFromHttpPostServer in
>   com.org.basepin.UserService$$ER2a9kvc |    184 | $tt__createRequest .
>   . . . . . . . in     '' |    437 | $tt__uploadClashImages
>   in     '' |   1325 | doCall . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in
>   com.org.basepin.UserController$_fetchClashReportImages |   1323 |
>   fetchClashReportImages             in com.org.basepin.UserController |
>   198 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . in
>   grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilt |     63 |
>   doFilter                           in
>   grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter |   1110 | runWorker . .
>   . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor |
>   603 | run                                in
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker ^    722 | run . . . .
>   . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread

```
BuildConfig.groovy dependencies{

 compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.4'){
             excludes "commons-codec"
         }
         compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.2'){
             excludes "commons-codec"
         }
         compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3'){
             excludes "commons-codec"
         }
         //compile "org.grails.plugins:rest:0.8"

        runtime('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.4'){
            excludes "commons-codec"
        }
        runtime('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.2'){
            excludes "commons-codec"
        }
        runtime('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3'){
            excludes "commons-codec"
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a quick glance, I would assume that httpmime 4.3 uses that Args class, and it's expecting it to be supplied by the httpcore dependency.  You aren't depending on version 4.3 of httpcore, and that would appear to be when it was introduced.

Update your httpcore dependency to 4.3, and this error should resolve.  While you're at it, I'd make all three of these dependencies use the same version, or you might see another of these errors crop up.

Comment: Thank you so much
I 've updated only httpcore dependency to 4.3.2 and it works :)